# How to fill in ListView control with List<MWifi> in android?

Tags: android

I know I can use  SimpleCursorAdapter as data soure to fill in ListView conrol item, now I design a data structure named MWiFi,and add data to List<MWifi>  structure.

I hope to fill the  MWiFi.name of  List<MWifi>  in ListView control item and bind  MWiFi.wifiID of  List<MWifi>  to the corresponding item , how can I do? Thanks!

```
public class MWiFi {
    public int wifiID;
    public String name;
    public Boolean enabled;
    public int networkID;
    public String description;


    public MWiFi(){
        name="";
        enabled=true;
        networkID=-1;
        description="";
    }

}
```

Comment: with ArrayAdapter<MWiFi> or any other Adapter ... where is the problem? you can find countless examples over the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the corresponding TextView objects in your list item layout.

One for each attribute/property of MWiFi that you want to expose to the UI.

Also, you don't need a SimpleCursorAdapter (or any subclass of CursorAdapter) if you are not pulling the values from a database.

If you are using List, you will need to work with an ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Thanks, can I bind wifiID of MWiFi to item when I use ArrayAdapter? can you show me some sample code?

Comment: here is an example that uses ArrayAdapter. Search for "ArrayAdapter with custom object" if you need help with mapping custom object properties to UI elements/widgets.